# Suppose that $L(\alpha)/L/K$ and that $[K(\alpha):K]$ and $[L:K]$ are relatively prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose that $L(\alpha)/L/K$ and that $[K(\alpha):K]$ and $[L:K]$ are relatively prime. Show that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$ has its coefficients in $K$.

I tried an approach but I got stuck:

We have that the following field extensions: $L(\alpha)/L$ and $L/K$ and we have the following fact that $[L:K]$ and $[K(\alpha):K]$ are relatively prime.

From this: it is safe to assume that $[K(\alpha): K] < \infty$ thus $\alpha \in K$ is algebraic over K.

Also: $[L(\alpha): K] = [L(\alpha): L][L : K]$ and $[L:K] = [L:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K]$ (I feel like this isn't true because $[L:K]$ and $[K(\alpha):K]$ are relatively prime.)

Now I've tried to do things but I couldn't progress anywhere. How would I show that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$ has coefficients in $K$?

Comment: you can't use the symbol $ [L:K(\alpha)]$ unless $\alpha \in L$ which is not assumed to be the case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 2):

the basic numerical law for finite extensions is:
$$
[L(\alpha):K] = [L(\alpha):K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K] = [L(\alpha):L][L:K]
$$
thus because of the data on relative primality:
$$
[K(\alpha):K]|[L(\alpha):L]
$$
and in particular, therefore:
$$
[K(\alpha):K] \le [L(\alpha):L] \le [L(\alpha):K]
$$
which makes the required point, since, because $K \subset L$ we must have 
$$
[L(\alpha):L] \le [K(\alpha):K]
$$

Comment: I'm lost with this: I don't get how if $K \subset L$ implies that $[L(\alpha): L] \le [K(\alpha): K]$ or how you get $[K(\alpha):K] \le [L(\alpha):L] \le [L(\alpha):K]$ from the 2nd step either.

Comment: (a) since $K \subset L$ any polynomial with coefficients in $K$ is ipso facto a polynomial with coefficients in $L$.

Comment: (b) if $a | b$ then a fortiori $a \le b$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $[L:K]$ and $[K(\alpha):K]$ are finite and relatively prime. The minimal polynomial $p$ of $\alpha$ over $L$ divides the minimal polynomial $q$ of $\alpha$ over $K$. The degree of $q$ is $[K(\alpha):K]$, so the degree of $p$ divides the degree of $q$. Furthermore, $\deg p=[L(\alpha):L]$, and since $K(\alpha)\subset L(\alpha),\deg q$ divides $[L(\alpha):K]$. Set $n=\deg q/\deg p$. Then $n$ divides $[L(\alpha):K]/[L(\alpha):L]=[L(\alpha):K]/\deg p=[L:K].$ But $n$ also divides $\deg q$, which is relatively prime to $[L:K]$, so $n=1$.

Comment: Hey, I just fully read through your solution. I see that if $n = 1$, they are the same degree. But how does that imply that $\alpha$ over $L$ has coefficient in $K$? The only thing I can work my way around this is if the minimal polynomial of $L$ is the same as the minimal polynomial of $K$.

Comment: Ah, yes-$p/q$ must have degree $0$, thus be some $\beta\in L$. Then $\beta^{-1} p=q$ is also a minimal polynomial of  $\alpha$ over $L$: minimal polynomials are only defined up to a unit. (Alternatively, if your minimal polynomials are monic, then $\beta$ must be $1$.) So the point is indeed that $\alpha$ has the same minimal polynomial over $L$ as over $K$.

Comment: You say that $p(x) \mid q(x)$ $\implies \operatorname{deg} p(x) \mid \operatorname{deg} q(x)$ but is that actually true?